# How do I vary speed of object parented to animated Bezier curve?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I am trying to animate an airplane flying a simple loop. The problem is that the airplane in my animation moves at a constant speed along the Bezier curve, whereas the speed of a real airplane would vary over time--slower on the climb and faster on the descent. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out a way to vary the speed of the airplane along the path. Maybe I set this up wrong? Can anybody help? (blend attached) Thanks. Blender 3.5.1, Windows 11

[Blender project file](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/airplane_loop_animation_debug2.blend)

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsOSDYTsG7o) YT video is for Blender 2.8 but the technique is the same for later versions.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this video once before, but could not make it work. I am trying it again and now I am getting good results. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Good to know! :^)

Answer (score 2):

The animation of your object is tied to the curve's "evaluation time" under its properties panel. By default this value expands at a linear rate, but if you right-click and select "clear keyframes" you can animate it manually.

[image: Properties > Object Data Properties > Path Animation > Evaluation Time]

Answer (score 2):

To add to Chloa's answer, if you do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>> *Follow Path*, it will automatically assign a *Generator* modifier to your curve that will determine the speed of the parented object along the curve and will prevent any keyframe on the *Evaluation Time*. To remove the *Generator* modifier, select your curve, open the *Graph Editor*, open the *N* panel, click on the *Modifiers* tab, close the *Generator* modifier (or as Chloa says, right click on the *Evaluation Time* and *Clear Keyframes*):

[image]

Now you can open the *Object Data* panel and under *Path Animation* you can keyframe the *Evaluation Time*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, when I do a Ctrl+P > Follow Path, no Generator modifier is added. I went through this with another video tutorial, but I can never get the Generator modifier to appear--Nevermind. The Generator appears in the Graph editor, not the 3D Viewport. :)